# IC to patch pins arbitrarily?

Tags: fpga, switches, integrated-circuit, embedded, latch

Is there an IC that will support patching pins together arbitrarily for AC or DC signals going in both directions across any patched pair of pins?

I'm pretty sure it could be done with an FPGA though I'm more interested in knowing if there is a name for a specific type of chip that does this for say 200 pairs of pins in any configuration (aside from manually daisy-chaining a bunch of latches together.)

This would primarily be for digital signals in the MHz range.

Comment: AC or DC signals; in the MHz range. Be clear please, are you talking about digital signals or analogue signals?

Comment: As in the equivalent of a switch.

Comment: The generic name for this type of part is "cross-point switch", but I  don't think you can get one that does 200 inputs and 200 outputs.  More typically you can get 8x8 and 16x16 switches.

Comment: Macom has [288x288](https://www.macom.com/products/product-detail?partNumber=M21170). But the 3 Gbps rate capability is overkill for you.

Comment: That is a serious piece of silicon. A bit out of my league.

Comment: when you say "primarily for digital signals in the MHZ range" do you mean that sometimes it won't be digital, or sometimes it won't be in the MHz range or both?

needing to do analog signals too means you need an analog crosspoint, which is a more complicated beast than a digital one which likely would be FPGAable.

Comment: A large crosspoint matrix can be assembled out of smaller crosspoints. For example, four 16x16 crosspoint switch ICs could be configured in a 2x2 matrix, to function as a 32x32 crosspoint (2x2 matrix of ICs, 32x32 matrix of signals). However each signal passes through multiple switches, accumulating propagation delay and distortion. A 256x256 crosspoint made of 16x16 crosspoints would require 256 of those 16x16 ICs, and since each signal passes through 16 switches, signal integrity may suffer. Can you explain generally why you want such a large crosspoint? Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: @MarkU: I don't know how you're imagining an array of chips would be hooked up. Even with a 16x16 array of chips, each signal only passes through one chip. However, each signal is *directly connected to* 16 chips -- all of the chips in a particular row or column. But only one of those chips will be activated to make a particular connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a huge number of crosspoint switch chips available; just search any electronics distributor's website. However, they are nearly all designed to switch high-speed digital signals in one direction only — a set of inputs is switched to a set of outputs.

But it sounds like you're looking for something more along the lines of an array of "bare" 4016/4066-type transmission gates that can pass current in both directions when activated. You're not going to find such a product commercially, mainly because there's no market demand to develop such a chip.

Every now and then, someone comes up with the idea that such a chip would be useful to build some sort of remotely-controlled prototyping board or something similar. However, CPLDs and FPGAs, which include both the switching AND the logic internally, are a much better answer for that.